# "Производственные" и "Исследовательские" языки программирования

Tags: любой-язык, терминология

Чем отличаются между собой `Производственные` и `Исследовательские` языки программирования? Что значат эти определения?

> Java — это, в первую очередь, **производственный**, а не **исследовательский** язык программирования, а потому, как указывал в своей классической работе по дизайну языка программирования Java Ч.Э.Р. Хоар (C.A.R. Ноаге), при его разработке создатели языка старательно избегали включения новых и неопробованных возможностей. [Источник](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/31953201/) (стр.23)

Comment: а где ты нашел эти определения?

Comment: Вероятно, что в книге где Вы нашли эти «определения»- там же и раскрывается их суть ;) В общепринятых подходах нет таких определений для языков программирования.

Comment: @TimurVI  Мне приходит в голову те старые времена, когда язык Алгол 60 использовался как средство описания алгоритмов, но не для исполнения его на конкретных машинах. Думаю, что сейчас это уже не актуально.

Comment: «Java — это, в первую очередь, ЯП для практических решений, а не исследований возможностей языка» - читайте так.

Comment: Скорее всего, производственные используются для написания бизнес-логики, а исследовательские - для использования математического аппарата.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow я читал ваш ответ, спасибо, он был мне интересен.

Comment: данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что его следует адресовать авторам книги, употребившем перечисленные термины.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Все просто

**Производственный язык** - это язык, на котором можно писать промышленный код. С/С++, Java, PHP и подобные. Эти языки хорошо стандартизированы и дают ожидаемый результат.

**Исследовательский язык** - язык, предназначенный для проведения исследований. На подобных языках редко пишут промышленный код. У этих языков два предназначения - проверить какую-то идею в программировании (когда то лямбды были исключительно здесь, а теперь в каждом промышленном языке) или для какой то задачи (эти языки ещё могут называть специализированные). К таким языкам относяти хаскель, ml и другие функциональные языки. Также, я бы отнес сюда dart (попытка сделать javascript  с человеческим лицом).

Конечно, никто не мешает на хаскеле писать промышленный код (энтерпрайз :) ), или на с написать исследования.

Языки могут со временем мигрировать с одной категории в другую. Когда то с++ был исследовательским языком, а теперь это нормальный промышленный язык.

Comment: _Конечно, никто не мешает на хаскеле писать промышленный код (энтерпрайз :) ), или на с написать исследования._ - тогда как можно разделять их, если на них тоже можно?

Comment: Ну вот, Вы старались, а там неправильное прочтение книги. Плюсик Вам.

Comment: @Grundy можно бензопилой пилить деревья, даже если туда не залить бензин. Тяжело конечно, но можно. И вполне даже может применятся (например, как наказание). Но это же не значит, что нужно везде так делать.

Comment: @KoVadim, но от этого бензопила ведь не перестанет быть бензопилой

Comment: А сколько ещё чудных вещей ею можно сделать! И при этом она остается обычной бензопилой. Поэтому все зависит только от разработчика. Хороший разработчик даже на самом ужасном языке сделает лучше, чем плохой на самом лучшем языке.

Comment: используют. Никто не мешает. На производстве также могут быть исследовательские проекты.

Comment: Selectel пишут на Хаскеле системные утилиты. Они упоминали об этом на Хабре. Исключайте из списка исследовательских :-)

Comment: я даже боюсь спросить, что эти утилиты делают. Если они оперируют разделами диска, то я бы побоялся их запускать.

Comment: @KoVadim, почему же?

Comment: это насколько риторический вопрос и ответ на который насколько очевидный, что мне даже неловко писать его.

Comment: @KoVadim вы боитесь чистых функций при работе с диском?)

Comment: чистые функции - это хорошо. Но как чистая функция сможет что то поменять? Она уже не будет такой:)

Comment: @KoVadim, вроде монады как раз для такого используют?

Answer (score 1):

Могу предположить, что речь идет о двух видах языка: так называемые *академические* и *промышленные*.

Первый тип включает языки, которые используется для обучения программированию. У них, как правило, не сложный синтаксис, достаточно скудные языковые фичи. На таких языках, часто, не очень удобно писать большие программы.
Примером может служить: `Pascal`, `Basic`.

К промышленным относятся языки на которых пишут программы для повседневного использования.
Примеры: `Java`,`C++`,`Python` и пр.

Стоит сделать оговорку, что язык может принадлежать как к одной, так и к другой категории.